# Game requiring gamepad instead of tilt controls

Tags: game-controllers

When i start a game it starts with gamepad controls as default, i can't play the game .
How to change settings in Mobile to change input from controller to default tilt.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a global setting, it's specific to the game. You'll need to look in the settings inside the game and see if it has tilt controls. If it doesn't support tilt controls you're out of luck.