# Some games force use of gamepad controls instead of touch controls

Tags: 8.1-oreo, touch

I recently bought a new smartphone, it's a LG Q7 and it's running Android 8.1

With it I tried running various games, of which, two of them are **gear.club** and **Implosion - Never Lose Hope**. Although I wasn't able to play gear.club on my previous smartphone, I was able to play Implosion albeit a bit slowly and I know I can control the character via touch. In regards to gear.club, my brother played it on his phone and he was able to use touch but on my phone, those two games, when doing the tutorial, they show the buttons for a gamepad/controller and won't respond to any touch input I give them. I haven't yet connected any device to this smartphone.

What I tried:

- Going into settings and search for an options about controllers, couldn't find anything.
- Disabling the LG Gaming Extension but it does nothing ( it's used to change resolution and framerate)
- Contacting gear.club and implosion support to no avail

[This question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/186938/game-requiring-gamepad-instead-of-tilt-controls) might be similar but both in gear.club and Implosion there is no option to change from gamepad to touch controls.

Answer (score 1):

K. Try looking into the web View application. Is the Q7 using Chrome as web View or Google's web View from the play store?
They are different. You could be stuck in the web View or you've got an overlay app that you have to manually find by uninstalling one app at a time, checking to the if it works after each time. The update on Nov. 1, 2019 should have probably solved the issue. I like the increase to 9.0 system. Good luck. PS These phones are tanks! But, the framework leaves much to be desired.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. I'm curious why you mention the web view and overlay app. Did you experience a similar issue with a game forcing to use gamepad due to the web view and/or overlay app? AFAIK, these games don't use web view (i.e. not browser games), but a game engine utilizing graphic tech.